# Angular Switching stylesheets url's

Tags: css, angular

Hi I am new to angular,

If I want to change stylesheet for document in pure js I just simply do that by setting new href attribute:

```
document.getElementById("linkmarkerId").setAttribute("href", "./newstylesheeturl.css");
```

and I was wondering how can I do same thing in angular, so I can change the stylesheet url after e.g button click, so I tried:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [this.stylesheetUrl]
})
export class AppComponent {
    stylesheetUrl: String = './app.component.css';
    ...

}
```

but I noticed I can't access AppComponent class from @Component settings, so is whats the properway to set variable value for styleUrls ?